# Multiple conditions in while controller

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to add two conditions in while controller? My two conditions are `Complete ="True"` and `Results >200`.

I tried using it by setting `Complete = False` and `Results=0` in `user defined variables` and used it in `while controller` as follows:

`${__javaScript("${Complete}" != "true")} && ${__javaScript((parseInt(${Results}) >90)}`.

But it is looping indefinitely. Please help.

Comment: Are you resetting the values of `Complete` & `Results` inside `While Controller`? If not, loop can't be stopped.

Comment: I am resetting it in a BSF preprocessor as vars.put("Complete","false");
vars.put("Results",0);

Comment: added answer. pls try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following condition (working for me):

```
${__jexl3("${Complete}" == "False" && ${Results} >= 0,)}
```

where Complete - False & Results - 0.

For above values, condition will be evaluated to `true`, hence executes the children of the `While Controller`.

Note: Please change the conditions `==` & `>=` symbols and values `False` && `0` as per your requirements.

You must reset the values inside the `While Controller`, to make the condition evaluated to `false`, otherwise you will struck in infinite loop.

References:

1. https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller
2. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter

Comment: I tried it like you said with the change ${__javaScript("${Complete}" != "true" && ${Results} >= 200,)} and I also reset the values in bsf preprocessor as vars.put("Complete","false"); vars.put("Results",0); but still it is looping indefinitely

Comment: in your case, as `0 >= 200` returns `false`, overall condition becomes `false` and must come out of the loop. Please add `Debug sampler` inside the `While Controller` and check whether values are being updated or NOT. Don't use `bsf preprocessor`, which is deprecated. use `JSR223 preprocessor`

Comment: i used JSR223 preprocessor. In the debug sampler should I see the values set in the JSR233 preprocessor or from the result itself? I am seeing the values from the result.

Comment: Yes, check in `View Results Tree` results of `Debug Sampler`

Comment: yes and I could see the values for Complete and Results extracted from the result in the debug sampler

Comment: please add screen shot of test plan highlighting while condition. and also check any errors in JMeter Log paner (top right corner)

Comment: added screenshot. also there are some errors that you can see

Comment: the condition is wrong. please look at my answer. I suggested different expression with only one `__javascript()` function. please use it as follows `${__javaScript("${Complete}" != "true" && ${Results} >= 200,)}`

Comment: I tried that, but when I added that it wouldn't run the test. It stopped within a second.

Comment: that's what you need right. initialize with different values so the condition will be true in the first iteration (provide Complete -> false & result=201 in UDV to make condition evaluated to `true`) .

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple Condition in While Loop using Groovey Function for '&&' and '||' for the same field.

```
${__groovy(!(vars.get('ocrstatus_1').equals('500') || vars.get('ocrstatus_1').equals('1000')) ,)}
```